# Verilog counter delay in task not working

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, synthesis

I'm trying to generate different delays in multiple places using `task` `WAIT` in a synthesizable module, and the code is as follows:

```
 module LCD
  (
    input          clk,
   output         en
 
  );  
     reg [ 15 : 0 ] delay = 0;         //  counter for state machine
     reg [ 15 : 0 ] COUNT= 0;          // counter  for "WAIT"
    
     always @ (posedge clk_lcd) begin
     
          COUNT = COUNT + 1'b1;        // COUNTER FOR TASK "WAIT"
                           .
          delay = 2000;
          WAIT(en, delay);             // call task
               .
          delay = 500;
          WAIT(en, delay);             // call task
     end                               // always end
               .                    
     
     task automatic WAIT               // task to wait till delay time is up
     (     
       output EN,
       input [ 15 : 0 ] DELAY
      );
    begin                              
       COUNT = 0;
       if(COUNT == DELAY)begin         // create delay using counter                                                
          EN = 0;                                                        
          COUNT = 0;
       end else begin    
          EN = 1;                                                        
          COUNT = COUNT + 1'b1;  
       end                                        
    end
    endtask                            //  end task
  endmodule
```

But, they don't work. I'm a learner; please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to Verilog, here is a quick start to learn about [synthesizable constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs).  It is not common to use a `task` for synthesizable code; they are much more common for non-synthesizable testbench code.

As I'm sure you have already discovered if you tried to simulate or synthesize your code, the code has several syntax errors.  This requires a new approach.  Generally, a counter can be coded with a simple `always` block, and there is no need for a task.  Instead of writing code to sequentially load the counter with 2 delay values like that, use a state variable to keep track of the delay.  Here is a common way to code up a counter:

```
module LCD (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output reg en
);  
    reg state;
    reg  [15:0] COUNT;
    wire [15:0] DELAY = (state) ? 500 : 2000;
    
    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            COUNT <= 0;
            state <= 0;
            en <= 0;
        end else if (COUNT == DELAY) begin
            COUNT <= 0;
            state <= ~state;
            en <= 1;
        end else begin
            COUNT <= COUNT + 1'b1;
            en <= 0;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

The enable is a pulse that goes high for 1 cycle every time the counter reaches the delay value.  This should get you moving in the right direction.